# Looking for alternative to RoboForm's SearchCards

Tags: firefox, search, software-rec, macros, roboform

I use Palemoon (a Firefox build) on Windows 7 x64 and I've recently migrated from RoboForm to LastPass for my password keeping needs.

The only thing I miss from RoboForm, was it's ability to let me create and use [SearchCards](http://www.searchcardplace.com/). So, is there any add-on or service that imitates the ability to create my own *1-step* and *3-step* searches (by recording search macros) as I used to do with RoboForm's SearchCards?

Comment: I've started using OpenSearch and while Mycroft project is helping, still I can't replicate the 3-step SearchCards I had created, so I am continuing looking for an alternative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iMacros for IE / Firefox / Chrome. That is a *free* web browser macro recorder addon, and you can automate all kinds of web browsing. Automating a Google or Bing search is **very** easy with it.

http://www.iopus.com/imacros/compare/all/ (see the free addons on the right!)